# Sitecore Tracker is null after login with specified user

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-xdb

I've doubt related with Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker and how sitecore tracks user information.
This is the current version that i'm using - Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519) with MVC

I have a page for Login where I'm doing the manual login against sitecore and Tracker.Current is always null.

And i want to create a Contact for the logged in user, or validate if there's any, to fill user info.

Searched in showconfig.aspx for Analytics.Enabled and there were no results in it. All database connection strings are correct.

Thanks in advance.

Code example:

```
string domainUser = Sitecore.Context.Domain.GetFullName(model.Username);

if (System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(domainUser) != null)
{         
   bool logged = AuthenticationManager.Login(domainUser, model.Password, false);
   ....
}
```

UPDATE:

```
ViewBag.XdbSettings = "Empty";
if (XdbSettings.Enabled)
    ViewBag.XdbSettings = "Enabled";

ViewBag.HasValidLicense = "Empty";
if (XdbSettings.HasValidLicense)
    ViewBag.HasValidLicense = "HasValidLicense";

ViewBag.Tracking = "Empty";
if (XdbSettings.Tracking.Enabled)
    ViewBag.Tracking = "Enabled";

ViewBag.Comment = "Empty";
if (Tracker.Current != null)
    ViewBag.Comment = "Not Null";


XdbSettings: Enabled
HasValidLicense: HasValidLicense
Tracking: Enabled
Comment: Empty
```

Comment: How is your custom Login page implemented? Is it handled by Sitecore?

Comment: Hello Dmytro, thanks for replying.

I edited the post to show the login example but the Tracker is null in the page load already.

Comment: Have you set up the `analytics` connection string? Please check if you have any interactions saved in your MongoDB database.

Comment: Also, check that the `enableTracking` attribute is set to `true` for the appropriate `<site>` element in your Sitecore.config.

Comment: Thanks, but in the login page i need to initialize Tracker.Initialize(); to access tracker.current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sitecore 8.1, the name of the setting you're looking for has changed to `Xdb.Enabled`. You should check for both `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` to be present and set to `true`. These settings are located in *App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Xdb.config*.

Also, verify that you have other xDB-specific configuration files, such as *Sitecore.Analytics.config* and *Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config*.

Also, check that the `enableTracking` attribute is set to `true` for the appropriate `<site>` element in your Sitecore.config.

Also, follow this [**troubleshooting guide**](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445) by Sitecore.

Comment: Also make sure that you have a specific 8.1 licence file. The licence file changed from 8.0 to 8.1 and although 8.0 licence files work, you need the 8.1 specific file to enable the xDB

Comment: Thanks you both i will try to check the license correct version of it.

About the Sitecore.Xdb.Config it's correct implemented

Comment: Thanks it solved with enabletracking in sitecore.config and also rolling back some changes in Sitecore.Analytics.config